# Visual Studio has stopped working when the solution was opened?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

In my system, when i am trying to open the WPF application in Visual Studio (in all the framework), Visual Studio has shut down immediately with the popup saying "Visual Studio has stopped working". This happened only when opening the WPF applications. If i tried to work with UWP applications, nothing wrong with my visual studio and it was working without crashing.

Also i tried some possible ways which is go through from online. I tried the following
1) clearing the temp data from the below folder.
"C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0"

2) Re-installed my visual studio and also reset the settings from Import and Export settings available in options.

But these are not helpful for me. Still i am facing the same problem only when tried to open the WPF application.

Can anyone suggest me to resolve this?

Thanks.

Comment: I have tried with re-installing VisualStudio, but still the same problem is occurred.

Answer (score 1):

It sometimes helps to delete the .suo file of the solution you are trying to open. Make sure you are displaying hidden files in Explorer. You can find the .suo file in the following folder: SolutionFolder.vs\SolutionName\v14